# ¿Cuando una vista necesita viewModels?

Tags: android, android-fragment, viewmodel

¿Cuando un `activity/fragment` requiere una referencia con un `view model`?

Para tener un contexto: estoy desarrollando una aplicación, y en ciertas `layout` simplemente es pasar *datos de formulario a otros* `layouts` de *formulario* (es decir *formularios* con tantos campos que hay que dividirlos en varias *layout*) en donde en la última *layout* se envían los datos a un `API`. En este sentido se debería crear una referencia al `viewmodel` que hace el llamado al *repositorio -> web service..etc*, con el último `fragment` asociado a la última `layout` que ya recopila la `data` de los formularios anteriores.

Comment: Bienvenido, es importante revisar [ask] para realizar preguntas en el sitio y estas sean bien recibidas, saludos.

Comment: Vale lo tendré en cuenta @Jorgesys